# How to put close button at jquery tooltip

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tooltip

I've used [this tooltip](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) at my webpage. Now, I want to put a "close button" in the tooltip, so if user click on that button, the tooltip will be closed(Though that tooltip close automatically after certain of time but I need to add close button feature too). This is my tooltip:

[image]

**I need when user click on the close button, the tooltip will be closed**.

I put my testing code at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YM84U/5/).

So, basically I hope, my code should be like this:

```
$('.tooltipster-content').on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('tooltipster-base').hide();
});
```

But, this code isn't working at my webpage.

Comment: You can use this link for the plugin : http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tooltipster/3.0.5/js/jquery.tooltipster.min.js

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my fiddle using your link. I hope, now everyone can understand my problem easily and can help me

Comment: Can you tell me one thing? How can I upload that kind of js or css file on such a link so that jsfiddle can load that?

Comment: You can check that http://geekdave.com/2013/06/19/linking-raw-github-files-from-jsfiddle/. If you're looking for a library it's probably already hosted by a cdn, otherwise I don't have another solution than copying and pasting your code in the jsfiddle (or jsbin).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because the event that you are delegating to in your fiddle is not present on the page when you're binding the event. Try the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('.tooltipster-base').hide();
});
```

In addition, you were missing the `.` on the front of the `$('.tooltipster-base')` jQuery selector within your bound `click` callback.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/warlock5658/YM84U/6/)**

Comment: Works also for me with Tipso I had done some tailoring to ... using '.boxclose' and $('.tipso_bubble').hide(), the former from stackoverflow.com/a/10019983/962391

Answer (score 2):

I think that it will be so more correct:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('.tooltip').tooltipster('hide');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/YM84U/19/)

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
$(".close").click(function(){
$(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Better to Edit tooltipster.min.js

find      `m.showTooltip();` in your tooltipster.min.js

Add below lines under `m.showTooltip();` in your tooltipster.min.js

```
$(".close").parent().parent().show();                               
$(".close").click(function(){$(this).parent().parent().hide();});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/YM84U/12/)

Comment: This is not working! My fiddle is now updated: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YM84U/5/ You can take a look and test now at there. Thanks

Comment: Close doesn't exist at the point that the event handler is being bound. This will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is updated solution for `tooltipster^4.0`:

```
functionReady: function (instance, helper) {
    $(instance._$tooltip).on('click', '.close-btn', function () {
        instance.close();
    });
}
```