# Tooltip doesn't come after closing it by close button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-tooltip

This is one kind of repeating question of this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24631883/how-to-put-close-button-at-jquery-tooltip/24633260?noredirect=1#comment38178501_24633260) As I ended(accepted answer) that question already, I can't update that question. By the way, That question is solved. But, I'm facing a new problem now. Here is my [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YM84U/9/)

There are two lines at my fiddle. I've used [this tooltip plugin](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/). Both have it's own tooltip(First line containing "First Tooltip" and Second line containing "Second Tooltip"). I put a close button in the tooltips. When, user click on the close icon, tooltip will be closed. But the problem is, if user close the "First Tooltip" by clicking close icon, that tooltip will be closed. After being closed, if the user hover on the text again(First line), that tooltip("First Tooltip") won't come again. That will come only after being open "Second Tooltip" by hover on second line. I'm trying to explain it more easily:

Normal Behave of tooltip:

> Text => mouse hover => Tooltip come => Move cursor from the "Text" =>
>   Tooltip gone => Bring back mouse pointer to "Text" => Tooltip come
>   again

My Issue:

> Text => mouse hover => Tooltip come => click the "Close" => Tooltip
>   gone => Bring back mouse pointer to "Text" => **Tooltip doesn't come**

This is the script for closing tooltip by clicking "close" icon:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function() {
    $('.tooltipster-base').hide();
});
```

How can I modify it so that after clicking "close" icon if the user put mouse pointer on that text again, the tooltip will come too again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hover over it again, you just need to wait a bit since the tooltip does not know it has closed yet..

This happens because you hide the tooltip with jquery and not through the tooltip plugin.

Use this instead

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster('hide');
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/YM84U/11/

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use this simple html- 
`<span title="this is tool tip.  Asdfghjkl zxcvbnm">?</span>` So when you mouse over on it, tool tip will come in 2 seconds.  Is it working ? Or I didnt understood your question ?

Comment: Basically, I'm using a plugin and keep everything like that. If it's hard to understand my problem, take a look on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/YM84U/10/ instead of my first